# Where do I have to mention the server URL in JNLP?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a desktop application. I want to launch that application using Web start. It is working fine. When I am launch it first time using browser then, it will download all jars defined in resources. But when next time I am run it again using JNLP or from browser, it will not downloading jars. It will used from cache memory of my system or some where else, I don't know..

I want that every time when my application is launch it will download all jars defined in resources.

Where do I have to mention the server URL in JNLP?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: how can i download jars from server side to local machine and access it from local path by jnlp?

Comment: *"access it from local path"*  The usual way is to specify `offline-allowed` in the JNLP & suggest desktop shortcuts and menu items.

Answer (score 1):

try to set update always in your jnlp-file: [oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#update)

For example:

```
<update check="always" policy="prompt-update">
```

It will force an update of the jar files, instead of using the ones from the cache.